# simply 2d array error-c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I define an array called "matriu":

```
#include "CQix.h"
#include "Graphics_Console.h"


class cTauler
{

CQix Qix;
HANDLE hScreen;
int iniciX, iniciY, fiX, fiY;

private:
bool matriu[38][28];

int area_activa;

};
```

And I want to initialize all values to false:

```
void cTauler::InicialitzarTauler()
{

int i,j;


for(i=0;i<=fiX+2;i++)
{
    for(j=0;i<=fiY+2;j++)
    {
        matriu[i][j]=false;
    }
}
```

But when I compile i get this error:
0xC0000005: Access violation.

So i tried to define the array doing this:

```
bool matriu[38][28]= {false};
```

And I can't compile because: "not allowing data member initializer"

What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you setting as the values for `fiX` and `fiY`?

Comment: You're getting an Access Violation because your loops no doubt iterate past the end of the array indexes.. Debug that first.

Comment: If `38` and `28` are specified at compile time, what is the point of having the variables `fiX` and `fiY`? I would rather have two constants (e.g. enums), one for row dimension, another for column dimension

Comment: "i<=fiX+2" <- that is _probably_ the error; though we can't really tell unless we see more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If the data `matriu[38][28]` is going to be always the same size, consider creating `const static` classmembers `fiX` and `fiY` and initialize them to values 38 and 28. You have probably not initialized them correctly...

Comment: found the error.
for(i=0;i<=fiX+2;i++)
{
    for(j=0;i<=fiY+2;j++)
    {
        matriu[i][j]=false;
    }
}

infinite bucle..have to change that 'i' for 'j'. So sad..thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop has a faulty stop condition of

```
i<=fiY+2
```

'j' will increment through the inner for-loop, but it will not stop because 'i' is not incremented within the inner loop.

Your error is just a result of a typo. Change the inner loop to

```
for(j=0;j<=fiY+2;j++)
```